# Applying Custom Slider in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I want to create a custom slide, however I do not know how to apply it in IB.

.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    UISlider                *customSlider;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UISlider *customSlider;

@end
```

.m

```
#define kSliderHeight            7.0
#define kViewTag                1  

@implementation MainViewController

- (UISlider *)customSlider
{
    if (customSlider == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(174, 12.0, 120.0, kSliderHeight);
        customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [customSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        customSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
        UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeslide.png"]
                                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowslide.png"]
                                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        [customSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [customSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [customSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        customSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
        customSlider.maximumValue = 100.0;
        customSlider.continuous = YES;
        customSlider.value = 50.0;

        [customSlider setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"CustomSlider", @"")];

        customSlider.tag = kViewTag;
    }
    return customSlider;
}
```

All I need to know is how I apply it in IB. As its an succesful build.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom class that is a subclass that inherits UISlider that does this setup in the init methods.

From there in interface builder just drop a normal UISlider in and on the Identity tab of the Inspector window change the class to your custom class.

in your MySlider.h:

```
@interface MySlider : UISlider
{

// Anything relevant you might want to change

}
@end
```

And in the .m file:

```
@implementation MySlider

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
        UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeslide.png"]
                                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowslide.png"]
                                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        [self setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.minimumValue = 0.0;
        self.maximumValue = 100.0;
        self.continuous = YES;
        self.value = 50.0;

        [self setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"CustomSlider", @"")];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: "You could make a custom class that is a subclass that inherits UISlider that does this setup in the init methods." How would I do that?

Comment: Do it exactly as written above (although you might want to modify the init method to have it return id)

Comment: Would I just add  that to the .m, and what would need changing in the .h - And this replaces the existing code right?

Comment: Correct, once you generate the class, fill in the blanks, all the .h needs is the `: UISlider` portion. You'll still have to tie your actions via interface builder, but the new custom class should handle the initial configuration

Comment: Hmm 
I've added
 UIColor  *backgroundColor; to .h

24: error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

I get that error on this line
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: backgroundColor should implicitly be inherited from UISlider, you shouldn't need to add things like that to the header

Comment: But UISlider    *customSlider; Has already been added to the .h
It says
error: request for member 'backgroundColor' in something not a structure or union

Comment: In your MainViewController you should be referring to the custom MySlider class and not the UISlider class. When you say the .h is it the MainViewController.h? or the MySlider.h?

Comment: Oh my bad - right its succesfully built. I'm in the nib and on the class identify I have chosen 'MySlider' However its hasnt changed.

Comment: It will looks the same in IB, but should change when it's running in the Simulator or on a device.

Comment: Hmm It hasnt changed when running on the sim or device

Comment: Try overriding `initWithCoder:` as well and putting breakpoints in to make sure the code is hitting it.

Comment: Oh, does anything have to be in the .h & .m of MainviewController?

Comment: You need to have IBOutlet/IBAction connections to the instance of your slider hooked up to your NIB in your main view controller

Comment: Ok IBOutlet UISlider *customSlider; has been added to the .h of mainviewcontroller

Comment: You need to make sure that `self = [super init]` doesn't return `nil`.